# Tab navigation vs long scroll

Tags: navigation, scrolling

I'm working on an educational course page, I would like to take the approach of a long scroll. e.g having the description and benefits then following are the speakers the following the syllabus, then requirements and last is price and apply button.

or have it all in 4 tabs e,g description | speakers | requirements | pricing

So was wondering what will be the better way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like ScrollSpy: See an example on the [Bootstrap website](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy). Or instead of tabs Bootstrap has the Affix menu as used on the [Bootstrap website too](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix).

[Here](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-scrollspy.php) you can find some great examples too.

Comment: That would be the happy middle for my issue probably i will test that , thanks

Comment: I find this design feature becoming a noticeable trend in modern website that focus on content (that "tells" a story). Having a continuous page creates a cohesive flow and the links still provide a quick way to navigate to other content.

Comment: Yeah, that the thing i like using long scroll .. but Its good if the user can skip quickly between the subjects.. when needed ..